# ojdbc6.jar; error in opening zip file

Tags: java, sqlexception, ojdbc

I am getting below exception while execution sql statements?
**Bigger type length than Maximum**

I searched on google and found that many suggested to use later version of oracle drivers.
As of now I am using ojdbc14.jar file . I downloaded new versions from Oracle site  ojdbc14.jar, ojdbc5.jar and ojdbc6.jar. But now eclipse is unable to create build. Giving error message :
**error: error reading D:\Prop1\RP1\Web\WEB-INF\lib\ojdbc6.jar; error in opening zip file**

any clues why above errors ?

I have jdk1.6, Tomcat 6.0 , Oracle 10g .

Comment: corrupted jar file? validate md5 after downloading

Answer (score 0):

Your  "lib"  folder (and classpath actually) must contain only one copy of driver.